# Graphs of diameter 2

Tags: graph-theory

How can I prove that $G$ (a simple graph) having diameter $2$ and $\Delta(G)=n-2$ has $m\geq 2n-4$, where $n$ is the number of vertices and $m$ is the number of edges.

This doesn't look like a very hard problem, I don't know why but it confuses me a lot. I would really like to see how one *should* solve it (since I'm self-studying graph theory I think most of my proofs tend to be kind of ad hoc and messy).

Comment: Is $\Delta(G)$ the maximum degree in $G$?

Comment: @Paul: Yes, it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $v$ be a vertex of degree $n - 2$ and let $w$ be the unique vertex not adjacent to $v$.  Every neighbor of $w$ is also a neighbor of $v$.  Since $G$ has diameter exactly $2$, $w$ is adjacent to some neighbor of $v$.  Let $s = \deg(w)$.  Because $G$ has diameter $2$, each of the $n - 2 - s$ neighbors of $v$ that are not neighbors of $w$ must be adjacent to some neighbor of $w$.  Hence, there are a total of at least
$$(n - 2) + s + (n - 2 - s) = 2n - 4$$
edges in $G$.

Comment: Thank you, this is a nice proof.